# Laravel Routing does not work with post

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use RESTful Routing in Laravel and i'm encountering the following problem. My page consist of 2 Dropdowns, and a submit button. Upon loading the page for the first time, the show() function in Controller populates both of the dropdowns with results from 2 database queries.
After i have selected a value in each of the dropdowns and hit the submit button, i would like the page to display the results of another query as a table.

My show() method works, since the dropdowns are populated as they should. I have used the store() method to handle the post (after hitting the submit), but it gives me a blank page instead.

Route:

```
 Route::resource('web_tools', 'WebController');
```

Controller:

```
 class WebController extends BaseController {
       public function show() {
              $filters = WebToolsPage::QueryFilters();
              $category = WebToolsPage::QueryCategory(); 

              return View::make('top_pages.table',
              ['Filter'=>$filters, 'Category'=>$category]);
       }

       public function store() {
              $filt = Input::get('filt');
              $cat  = Input::get('cat');
              $filters = WebToolsPage::QueryFilters(); 
              $category = WebToolsPage::QueryCategory();
              $query = WebToolsPage::QueryTable($filt, $kat);
              return View::make('top_pages.table',
              ['Webmasters'=>$query,'Filter'=>$filters, 'Category'=>$category]);
       }

       public function index(){}
       public function create(){}
 }
```

View:

```
 {{Form::open()}}

 {{ Form::select('filt', $Filter) }}  
 {{ Form::select('kat', $Kategorie) }}

 {{ Form::Submit('Filter') }}

 ......

 {{Form::close()}}
```

My Model contains the 3 Queries, 2 for the dropdowns and 1 for table to be called within the second controller method.
I would also like to mention that everything works perfectly when i use Route::controller(...). And because i was getting errors about methods missing in my controller, i just went ahead and defined these methods and left them empty (?).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `show` method should accept an identifier as the first an only parameter, i.e. `show($id)` to identify the resource being shown.

Answer (score 0):

So i solved the blank page problem by adding the route name and controller-method name that was to be called after POST to the argument of the Form::open() method.

Like this:

```
 {{Form::open(['route' => 'web_tools.store'])}}

 {{ Form::select('filt', $Filter) }}  
 {{ Form::select('kat', $Kategorie) }}

 {{ Form::Submit('Filter') }}

 ......

 {{Form::close()}}
```

Now i'm able to see the table but the only problem is that the URI does not include the action name now.

i wanted:

```
 .../web_tools/store
```

but now have:

```
 .../web_tools
```

Anybody with any tips?

Answer (score 0):

A resource isn't supposed to have the method name in the URL. When you do a `POST`-request to `/web_tools`, the `store()` method is called. If you do a `GET`, `index()` will be called. Refer to the table in the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers):
[image: Resourceful controllers]

## Explicit route naming

If you want the explicit naming you would have to register it as a controller instead and use the RESTful method naming pattern:

In your `routes.php`:

```
Route::controller('web_tools', 'WebController');
```

and in your `WebController.php`:

```
class WebController extends BaseController {
       public function getShow() {
              $filters = WebToolsPage::QueryFilters();
              $category = WebToolsPage::QueryCategory(); 

              return View::make('top_pages.table',
              ['Filter'=>$filters, 'Category'=>$category]);
       }

       public function postStore() {
              $filt = Input::get('filt');
              $cat  = Input::get('cat');
              $filters = WebToolsPage::QueryFilters(); 
              $category = WebToolsPage::QueryCategory();
              $query = WebToolsPage::QueryTable($filt, $kat);
              return View::make('top_pages.table',
              ['Webmasters'=>$query,'Filter'=>$filters, 'Category'=>$category]);
       }

       public function getIndex(){}
       public function getCreate(){}
 }
```

## The Post/Redirect/Get pattern

**Also, you should really follow the PRG (Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.** In your store() method, what you actually want to do is this:

```
       public function store() {
              $filt = Input::get('filt');
              $cat  = Input::get('cat');
             //Store whatever you want to store
              return Redirect::action(self::class."@index");
       }
```

## Resourceful routing in general

In the first place, I think you misunderstood resourceful controllers and routing. They're used for *resources* (i.e. something represented in a database; users, posts, comments, etc..), so the `store`-method should actually persist(store) a new resource in the database. Lets take a User for a resource:

- **GET /user:** `index()`: Shows a list of users
- **GET /user/create:** `create()` Shows a form where you enter your credentials to create a new user (form posts to /user)
- **POST /user:** `store()` Saves the new user in a database (and redirects if you follow the PRG-pattern!)
- **GET /user/1:** `show(1)`: Shows user with an id of 1's profile
- **GET /user/1/edit:** `edit(1)`: Shows a form where you can change user 1's information (form posts to /user/1)
- **PUT /user/1:** `update(1)`: (A POST request with a hidden field in Laravel) Updates the user with an id of 1(f.
- **DELETE /user/1:** `destroy(1)`:  (A POST request with a hidden field in Larvel) Deletes the user with an ID of 1

Comment: I see that i've been going about the whole resourceful controllers and routing wrong. I failed to mention that i'm pretty new to this and this is my first laravel project. Would i get the method name in the URL if i used controller routing in the stead of resource routing? And since both my controller methods are retrieving data from a DB, which HTML Verbs would you say is correct/good practice for me to use? The first method, `show` will be called upon initial loading of the page. The second method `store` is used to populate a table after `submit` button is clicked upon.

Comment: Yes, you would get the method name in the URL using the controller routing. I guess you meant to say HTTP verbs. Your two names, `show` and `store` are correct. However, it depends on whether you're *updating* or *inserting new* data, in which cases you would use (in order) `update` and `store`. If you're making a filter, I'd just make a GET request to `index` with get-paramters (`http://example.com/web_tools?filter=...`). Your form will take care of that if you just put `method="GET"` in the `form`-tag.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, i meant HTTP Verbs. I'm making a filter with the `show` method and the `store` method does not actually insert any data, it just retrieves data from a DB with the new filters from `show`. This means that it will use the variables that are in `POST`. (Form::open(...))
If i include `method="GET"` within the `form-tag`, the method `store` completely ignores the variables in `POST`.

Comment: Yes indeed, but if I were you, I'd restructure. Forget using the `show` method with a filter. Thats still the `index`'s responsibility. `show` is meant to show *a single, specific resource*, not a list, even though it's narrowed down with a filter. Everything you're mixing together with 2/3 methods (`index` , `store` and `show`) should actually be contained inside `index`. Why do you want to use `$_POST` for a filter anyway? It's a bad habit.

Comment: Say you had a webshop and your customer used a filter to narrow down his search. Say he added some price filter, size and color. Now, he bookmarks that (as he doesn't know better). Next time he tries to find his search again, it's gone because you can't bookmark a POST-request. Say 80 % of the customers are interested in that search. It won't be indexed on Google. Bad SEO. Also, by the very nature, you're still `GET`ting products/tools/whatever, even though they're narrowed down with a filter.

Comment: So what I'm saying: Instead of locking your mind onto the logic it grasps right now, try to open up, try to understand the concept and adapt to it. In the end, that makes you a better developer and ultimately team-player.

Comment: Good points there. So basically all i need here is the ìndex`.The only reason why i require `$_POST` is because i need the dropdown selections after the `submit` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69114/discussion-between-tony-okoth-and-dencker).